# Why $SL$-invariants and highest weight vectors of rectangular shape coincide?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, general-linear-group

The groups $\mathrm{SL}(n) := \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n) = \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^n$ by multiplication from the left. This induces the diagonal action on $\bigotimes^M \mathbb{C}^n$. Consider two spaces:

- $A = \mathrm{HWV}^{\mathrm{GL}(n)}_{n \times k}\bigotimes^{nk} \mathbb{C}^n$ be the highest weight space of (rectangular) weight $n\times k$ with respect to the group $\mathrm{GL}(n)$.
- $B = \left(\bigotimes^{nk}\mathbb{C}^n\right)^{\mathrm{SL}(n)}$ be the space of $SL(n)$-invariants in the tensor space.

How to prove that $A = B$?

I know constructive proof using Schur-Weyl duality (for both groups). This envolves construction of a spanning sets for each space $A$ and $B$. These spanning sets coincide so the proof follows. But this proof is somewhat indirect and therefore unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$SL(n)$ is normal in $GL(n)$ so an irreducible $GL(n)$ representation contains an  $SL(n)$-invariant vector iff the whole thing is $SL(n)$-invariant and the representation factors through the determinant map $GL(n) \to GL(n) / SL(n) \cong \mathbb{C}^*$. Irreducible (holomorphic) representations of $\mathbb{C}^*$ are just powers of the standard one, so irreducible representations of $GL(n)$ with $SL(n)$ invariants are just powers of the determinant -- which in terms of weights are exactly these $n \times k$ rectangular ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can see that if vector is $SL(n)$-invariant then it is a highest weight vector of desired weight. How to show it the other way around, i.e. that highest weight vectors of rectangular weight are $SL(n)$ invariants? Also is it true that the statement  works for arbitrary underlying space $V$, not just the one I mentioned?

Comment: Could you @Nate please elaborate?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to elaborate on? As I explained above the irreducible $GL(n)$ representation corresponding to an $n \times k$ rectangle is one dimensional and is just $det^k$, which $SL(n)$ acts trivially on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I have a clear picture. I was missing the fact that $n \times k$ irrep is $1$ dimensional.